# AWSCLI: Can't specify db parameter group when creating mysql read replica

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli, read-replication

Using awscli, I'm trying to create a cross-region read replica, in us-west-1, of a mysql RDS in us-east-1. The db must have the lower_case_table_names parameter set to 1(default is 0). I have created a custom db parameter group with this setting. When I call "aws rds create-db-instance-read-replica" and specify my custom parameter group with "--db-parameter-group-name", the command fails with the following error:

An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateDBInstanceReadReplica operation: A parameter group can't be specified during Read Replica creation for the following DB engine: mysql

AWS documentation makes no mention of this limitation(that I can find). Obviously, in this case, changing the parameter group after the replicant is created is not an option. Has anyone else encountered this, and is there a work-around?

Edit: Wound up just letting the replica come up with default parameters. Even though that caused the replication to fail and left status at "error", once the replica was available I switched it to my custom parameter group. Then I rebooted it, and it came right up and replicated without issue. May not work in every case, but seems to have worked in mine.